# Python save to .txt

Tags: python-3.x

I have this program to generate random passwords. I'm trying to save it to the directory where the .py file is being executed. I.E if its in desktop i want the new .txt file to be saved in desktop.

This is the code i have tried:

```
base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

text_file = open(r'base_dir + mypassword', 'w')
text_file.write(password)
text_file.close()
```

Everything seems to be working fine except the part where it actually saves the .txt file with the newly generated password.

Comment: `'base_dir + mypassword'` is a literal string. Get rid of the quotes around `base_dir +`

Comment: Even then, `base_dir + mypassword` is going to need a proper path separator maybe with `os.path.join()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
text_file = open(base_dir+'/mypassword', 'w')
text_file.write('password')
text_file.close()
```

*** changed some code options to this:

```
base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))    
text_file = open(base_dir + '/mypassword.txt', 'w')
text_file.write(password)
text_file.close()
```

It's working perfectly now.

Comment: if i write ('password') isnt it just gonna write 'password' rather than the variable containing the actual password?

Comment: i tweeked it around a bit and it worked. im gonna edit your comment

Comment: I wrote 'password' as a representative but you are right

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current working directory with `os.getcwd()`. So you could try something like:

```
base_dir = os.path.getcwd()
filename = "my_file"

with open(f"{base_dir}/{filename}", 'w') as text_file:
    text_file.write(password)
```

Note how you can avoid having to deal with `.close()` your open file using context managers (using `with`).

Answer (score 2):

Pathlibs Path is another nice option that will work on all operating systems (the path separator is not the same in linux and windows for example):

```py
from pathlib import Path

with open(Path(filename), 'w') as file:
    file.write(password)
```

If you create a new Path it will automatically be relative to the current working directory.